# Box-sizing and Media Queries not working?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I would like to create a responsive page that

1. hides the right chat info box when the page is under 1000px wide

and

2. hides both the right chat box and left sidebar when the page is under 600px;

but I can't figure out what is wrong with my code that results in media queries not working.

Also, the searchbox in the left side bar is overflowing its parent even if I add "box-sizing: border" box to it.

The last question is that I would like to make the vertical side borders of the boxes to be the same height as the page height, without creating a side scroll bar (I tried making the boxed height: 100%, which was serviceable but it also created a side scrollbar, which is not allowed in this assignment).

Please have a look at my code below, thanks much:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1400px;) {
  .groupsettings,
  .search {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px;) {
  .groupsettings {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px;) {
  .search {
    display: none;
  }
}
.avatar {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 25px;
}
.chatroom {
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}
.groupprofile {
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
}
.groupsettings {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.grouptitle {
  grid-column: 2/4;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}
.his {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.his,
.mine {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 5px 10px 7px;
}
.loading {
  color: lightgray;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}
.logo {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 40px;
}
.messenger {
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 4fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}
.mine {
  align-self: right;
  background-color: #0097f7;
  color: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.name {
  color: lightgray;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  text-indent: 10%;
}
.normal {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.options {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.search {
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/3;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.searchbox {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.searchbox:focus {
  border: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
.settings {
  padding: 0px;
}
.steve {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
body {
  font-family: "SFUIText-Regular", "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica,
    Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
}
strong {
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Messenger</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="messenger">
      <div class="search">
        <strong>Messenger</strong>
        <input class="searchbox" placeholder="Search Messenger" />
      </div>
      <div class="grouptitle"><strong>normal group chat</strong></div>
      <div class="chatroom">
        <p class="mine">Hey man, hope everything's okay!</p>
        <p class="name">Steve</p>
        <div class="steve">
          <img
            class="avatar"
            alt="mine-craft-chara"
            src="https://i.imgur.com/R10B80x.png"
          /><span class="his"
            >All good man, those stacks of diamonds coming in hot!</span
          >
        </div>
        <p class="mine">Nice - make sure to save me some haha :D</p>
      </div>
      <div class="groupsettings">
        <div class="groupprofile">
          <img
            class="logo"
            alt="mine-craft-logo"
            src="https://i.imgur.com/vWJzAsu.jpg"
          />
          <span class="normal">normal group chat</span>
        </div>
        <div class="settings">
          <p class="options">Options</p>
          <p class="loading">Loading...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the semi colons after the max-width.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
  .groupsettings,
  .search {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .groupsettings {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .search {
    display: none;
  }
}
.avatar {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 25px;
}
.chatroom {
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}
.groupprofile {
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 10px;
}
.groupsettings {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  min-width: 300px;
}
.grouptitle {
  grid-column: 2/4;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}
.his {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.his,
.mine {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: max-content;
  padding: 5px 10px 7px;
}
.loading {
  color: lightgray;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}
.logo {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 40px;
}
.messenger {
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 4fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}
.mine {
  align-self: right;
  background-color: #0097f7;
  color: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.name {
  color: lightgray;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  text-indent: 10%;
}
.normal {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.options {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.search {
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/3;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.searchbox-container {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
  
.searchbox {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.searchbox:focus {
  border: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
.settings {
  padding: 0px;
}
.steve {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
body {
  font-family: "SFUIText-Regular", "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica,
    Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
}
strong {
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Messenger</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="messenger">
      <div class="search">
        <strong>Messenger</strong>
        <div class='searchbox-container'>
          <input class="searchbox" placeholder="Search Messenger" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grouptitle"><strong>normal group chat</strong></div>
      <div class="chatroom">
        <p class="mine">Hey man, hope everything's okay!</p>
        <p class="name">Steve</p>
        <div class="steve">
          <img
            class="avatar"
            alt="mine-craft-chara"
            src="https://i.imgur.com/R10B80x.png"
          /><span class="his"
            >All good man, those stacks of diamonds coming in hot!</span
          >
        </div>
        <p class="mine">Nice - make sure to save me some haha :D</p>
      </div>
      <div class="groupsettings">
        <div class="groupprofile">
          <img
            class="logo"
            alt="mine-craft-logo"
            src="https://i.imgur.com/vWJzAsu.jpg"
          />
          <span class="normal">normal group chat</span>
        </div>
        <div class="settings">
          <p class="options">Options</p>
          <p class="loading">Loading...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks much! That worked for the media query problem! But how should I resolve the search box in the left sidebar overflowing its parent? Also I notice there is gap forming between the bottom borders between boxes, which I think also belong to the same question as above, how should I fix this?

Comment: Fixed the issue regarding the search box. You have to remove the `margin: 10px` on the searchbox. If it doesn't have to be exactly 10px, you could go with like a `width: 90%` instead of 100%, or an alternative method would be to have a parent container with `padding: 10px` around it. I didn't understand what you meant regarding the borders.

Comment: Awesome I added a div to the searchbox and it worked! For the border problem I'll revise my question and upload a couple pics. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

you should add this to your head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Thanks, I added this line, what does it do?

Comment: it basically tells the browser that the website is expected to be a responsive website

Comment: Cool, notes taken. Thanks!